# I can pass a string in a variable to an Apex function. I can't pass a string literal

Tags: apex, javascript

This code results in this trace in the log.

javascript helper:

```
var bookname = 'Standard Price Book';
action.setParams({pricebookName: bookname});
action.setCallback(this, function(response) { ...
```

apex controller:

```
public static List<PricebookEntry> pdt_getProducts(String pricebookName) {
    system.debug('pricebookName:');
    system.debug(pricebookName);
```

log trace:

```
14:30:07:003    USER_DEBUG    [44]|DEBUG|pricebookName:
14:30:07:003    USER_DEBUG    [45]|DEBUG|Standard Price Book
```

---

However, this code results in this trace in the log.

javascript helper:  (passed a literal string)

```
action.setParams({pricebookName: 'Standard Price Book'});
action.setCallback(this, function(response) { ...
```

apex controller:  (unchanged)

```
public static List<PricebookEntry> pdt_getProducts(String pricebookName) {
    system.debug('pricebookName:');
    system.debug(pricebookName);
```

log trace:  (the literal is not passed through)

```
14:26:05:001    USER_DEBUG    [44]|DEBUG|pricebookName:
14:26:05:001    USER_DEBUG    [45]|DEBUG|null
```

---

It seems that a string literal and a string variable are not treated the same.  That makes it more difficult to make well-functioning programs quickly.

Comment: It would be great if someone could show me that I'm wrong, and you can pass literal strings.  I guess that's my question.  Can I pass literal strings?  If I can, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to fill out the `Javascript` with more complete context?

Comment: try double quotes

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you are not passing correct JSON in the second example. All JSON values can be:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array.

Ref [here](http://www.json.org/)

Change your call to:

```
action.setParams({"pricebookName": "Standard Price Book"});
```

If it still fails, you have found a bug. If not, Salesforce is parsing JSON to the letter of the API and has rejected your single quote enclosed string.

Comment: That is not JSON.  That is a Javascript object.  The single-quote and the double-quote are treated the same in Javascript.  If it were JSON, I would have to say {"pricebookName": "Standard Price Book"}.  Crockford didn't want to explain to folks that certain words were reserved (e.g. for) so he required that all the keys be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Pah!  Just to be complete, I tried it with double-quotes.  It worked.  I was  very confused.  So I went back to single-quotes.  It still worked.  Apparently, my system was in a strange state earlier when I encountered the problem.  I can't reproduce it.  Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly - I was meaning that the param is passed as JSON to the Salesforce backend and that it's possible that something is going wrong here - although it looks like it handles both Javascript objects and JSON objects just fine.